# onEdit in Script vs onEdit trigger / Column Width Script Not Working For Editors

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm a beginner and created a script to expand columns on 4 different tabs (A Sheet, B Sheet, C Sheet, D Sheet).

For myself, the script author, the script works fine on all tabs.

For invited editors, the script seems to work fine on the first tab (A Sheet) but does not work on the other tabs (B Sheet, C Sheet, D Sheet).

I tried adding a onEdit trigger which seems to fix this problem but now I'm receiving "Service using too much computer time for one day" errors.

On 8/27 I received a notice that the "Service using too much computer time for one day" error occurred 3 times. When I check My Executions logs I only see about 17 seconds of trigger time.

My questions are:

1) If I have onEdit(e) in my script code do I need an onEdit trigger?

2) Do I need to add onEdit(e) in my script code in more places such as above the B, C and D script sections?

3) Why does the script work for me, the author, but not the users with editing permissions.

4) Why do I receive "Service using too much computer time for one day" error notifications when my total execution duration time is well below the limit of 90min/day.

5) Can someone point me to good formating rules for script?

Thanks!

```
    function onEdit(e) {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("A Sheet");

  var clmnwdth = Sh1.getRange("G16:G27").getValues();
  var maxi = Math.max.apply(Math, clmnwdth);

  var clmn6 = Sh1.getRange("AB13:AE15");
  var clmn56 = Sh1.getRange("X13:AE15");
  var clmn456 = Sh1.getRange("T13:AE15");
  var clmn3456 = Sh1.getRange("P13:AE15");
  var clmn23456 = Sh1.getRange("L13:AE15");

  var clmn2 = Sh1.getRange("L13:O15");
  var clmn23 = Sh1.getRange("L13:S15");
  var clmn234 = Sh1.getRange("L13:W15");
  var clmn2345 = Sh1.getRange("L13:AA15");

 Logger.log(maxi); 

  if (maxi == 0) {
     Sh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 20, 5),clmn23456.setFontColor("white");
 } else if (maxi == 1) {
     Sh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 20, 5),clmn23456.setFontColor("white");
 } else if (maxi == 2) {
     Sh1.setColumnWidths( 16, 16, 5),Sh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 4, 100),clmn3456.setFontColor("white"),clmn2.setFontColor("black");
 } else if (maxi == 3) {
     Sh1.setColumnWidths( 20, 12, 5),Sh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 8, 100),clmn456.setFontColor("white"),clmn23.setFontColor("black");
 } else if (maxi == 4) {
     Sh1.setColumnWidths( 24, 8, 5),Sh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 12, 100),clmn56.setFontColor("white"),clmn234.setFontColor("black");
 } else if (maxi == 5) {
     Sh1.setColumnWidths( 28, 4, 5),Sh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 16, 100),clmn6.setFontColor("white"),clmn2345.setFontColor("black");
 } else {
     Sh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 20, 100),clmn23456.setFontColor("black");
  }  

  var BSh1 = ss.getSheetByName("B Sheet");

  var Bclmnwdth = BSh1.getRange("G16:G27").getValues();
  var Bmaxi = Math.max.apply(Math, Bclmnwdth);

  var Bclmn6 = BSh1.getRange("AB13:AE15");
  var Bclmn56 = BSh1.getRange("X13:AE15");
  var Bclmn456 = BSh1.getRange("T13:AE15");
  var Bclmn3456 = BSh1.getRange("P13:AE15");
  var Bclmn23456 = BSh1.getRange("L13:AE15");

  var Bclmn2 = BSh1.getRange("L13:O15");
  var Bclmn23 = BSh1.getRange("L13:S15");
  var Bclmn234 = BSh1.getRange("L13:W15");
  var Bclmn2345 = BSh1.getRange("L13:AA15");

 Logger.log(Bmaxi); 

  if (Bmaxi == 0) {
     BSh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 20, 5),Bclmn23456.setFontColor("white");
 } else if (Bmaxi == 1) {
     BSh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 20, 5),Bclmn23456.setFontColor("white");
 } else if (Bmaxi == 2) {
     BSh1.setColumnWidths( 16, 16, 5),BSh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 4, 100),Bclmn3456.setFontColor("white"),Bclmn2.setFontColor("black");
 } else if (Bmaxi == 3) {
     BSh1.setColumnWidths( 20, 12, 5),BSh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 8, 100),Bclmn456.setFontColor("white"),Bclmn23.setFontColor("black");
 } else if (Bmaxi == 4) {
     BSh1.setColumnWidths( 24, 8, 5),BSh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 12, 100),Bclmn56.setFontColor("white"),Bclmn234.setFontColor("black");
 } else if (Bmaxi == 5) {
     BSh1.setColumnWidths( 28, 4, 5),BSh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 16, 100),Bclmn6.setFontColor("white"),Bclmn2345.setFontColor("black");
 } else {
     BSh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 20, 100),Bclmn23456.setFontColor("black");
  } 
  var CSh1 = ss.getSheetByName("C Sheet");

  var Cclmnwdth = CSh1.getRange("G16:G27").getValues();
  var Cmaxi = Math.max.apply(Math, Cclmnwdth);

  var Cclmn6 = CSh1.getRange("AB13:AE15");
  var Cclmn56 = CSh1.getRange("X13:AE15");
  var Cclmn456 = CSh1.getRange("T13:AE15");
  var Cclmn3456 = CSh1.getRange("P13:AE15");
  var Cclmn23456 = CSh1.getRange("L13:AE15");

  var Cclmn2 = CSh1.getRange("L13:O15");
  var Cclmn23 = CSh1.getRange("L13:S15");
  var Cclmn234 = CSh1.getRange("L13:W15");
  var Cclmn2345 = CSh1.getRange("L13:AA15");

 Logger.log(Cmaxi); 

  if (Cmaxi == 0) {
     CSh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 20, 5),Cclmn23456.setFontColor("white");
 } else if (Cmaxi == 1) {
     CSh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 20, 5),Cclmn23456.setFontColor("white");
 } else if (Cmaxi == 2) {
     CSh1.setColumnWidths( 16, 16, 5),CSh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 4, 100),Cclmn3456.setFontColor("white"),Cclmn2.setFontColor("black");
 } else if (Cmaxi == 3) {
     CSh1.setColumnWidths( 20, 12, 5),CSh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 8, 100),Cclmn456.setFontColor("white"),Cclmn23.setFontColor("black");
 } else if (Cmaxi == 4) {
     CSh1.setColumnWidths( 24, 8, 5),CSh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 12, 100),Cclmn56.setFontColor("white"),Cclmn234.setFontColor("black");
 } else if (Cmaxi == 5) {
     CSh1.setColumnWidths( 28, 4, 5),CSh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 16, 100),Cclmn6.setFontColor("white"),Cclmn2345.setFontColor("black");
 } else {
     CSh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 20, 100),Cclmn23456.setFontColor("black");
  } 
  var DSh1 = ss.getSheetByName("D Sheet");

  var Dclmnwdth = DSh1.getRange("G16:G27").getValues();
  var Dmaxi = Math.max.apply(Math, Dclmnwdth);

  var Dclmn6 = DSh1.getRange("AB13:AE15");
  var Dclmn56 = DSh1.getRange("X13:AE15");
  var Dclmn456 = DSh1.getRange("T13:AE15");
  var Dclmn3456 = DSh1.getRange("P13:AE15");
  var Dclmn23456 = DSh1.getRange("L13:AE15");

  var Dclmn2 = DSh1.getRange("L13:O15");
  var Dclmn23 = DSh1.getRange("L13:S15");
  var Dclmn234 = DSh1.getRange("L13:W15");
  var Dclmn2345 = DSh1.getRange("L13:AA15");

 Logger.log(Dmaxi); 

  if (Dmaxi == 0) {
     DSh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 20, 5),Dclmn23456.setFontColor("white");
 } else if (Dmaxi == 1) {
     DSh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 20, 5),Dclmn23456.setFontColor("white");
 } else if (Dmaxi == 2) {
     DSh1.setColumnWidths( 16, 16, 5),DSh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 4, 100),Dclmn3456.setFontColor("white"),Dclmn2.setFontColor("black");
 } else if (Dmaxi == 3) {
     DSh1.setColumnWidths( 20, 12, 5),DSh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 8, 100),Dclmn456.setFontColor("white"),Dclmn23.setFontColor("black");
 } else if (Dmaxi == 4) {
     DSh1.setColumnWidths( 24, 8, 5),DSh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 12, 100),Dclmn56.setFontColor("white"),Dclmn234.setFontColor("black");
 } else if (Dmaxi == 5) {
     DSh1.setColumnWidths( 28, 4, 5),DSh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 16, 100),Dclmn6.setFontColor("white"),Dclmn2345.setFontColor("black");
 } else {
     DSh1.setColumnWidths( 12, 20, 100),Dclmn23456.setFontColor("black");
  } 
}
```

Comment: One thing that jumps out is that on each execution you're running a lot of getRange() calls that you ultimately don't need. It's probably not the whole reason, but you can speed things up if you only get the relevant ranges inside of whatever condition matches (which could be done more expressively as a switch)

Comment: Thanks! Could I nest the getrange statements under the if / else if statements?